# How to get app package name or applicationId using JNI android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

For the protection issue of the shared library I will try to get package name using JNI but it will give errors. So, is it possible to get package name or applicationId using JNI? If anyone have example or references for this problem then suggests. Because not any good tutorial or solution available. Else any other way suggest of the protection of the shared library.

Comment: no, you cannot "get package name or applicationId using JNI"

Comment: have any other solution for the protection.

Comment: what "protection" do you mean?

Comment: Reusability of the library, for example you create one shared library for your application but some attacker decompile apk and take shared library from the application. And reuse into other application.

Comment: so encrypt your .so file somehow

Comment: Unless you've got some sort of anti-tampering functionality in your native library it's probably not going to be very difficult for someone to patch away any checks that you do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Android is based on Linux, we can obtain a lot of information in user space provided by kernel.

In your example, the information stored here `/proc/${process_id}/cmdline`

We can read this file, and get the application id.

See a simple example

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAG "YOURAPPTAG"

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_x_y_MyNative_showApplicationId(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {

    pid_t pid = getpid();
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, "process id %d\n", pid);
    char path[64] = { 0 };
    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/cmdline", pid);
    FILE *cmdline = fopen(path, "r");
    if (cmdline) {
        char application_id[64] = { 0 };
        fread(application_id, sizeof(application_id), 1, cmdline);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, "application id %s\n", application_id);
        fclose(cmdline);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even more easily you can use `/proc/self/cmdline` and thereby skip the call to `getpid()`.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
  static jstring get_package_name(
      JNIEnv *env,
      jobject jActivity
  ) {
    jclass jActivity_class = env->GetObjectClass(jActivity);

    jmethodID jMethod_id_pn = env->GetMethodID(
        jActivity_class,
        "getPackageName",
        "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring package_name = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(
        jActivity,
        jMethod_id_pn);

    return package_name;
  }
```