# How to get versionName and versionCode from JNI to Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have tried searching but have not found anything, anyone can guide or any solution is appreciated.

**Edit**
I would like to get information like versionCode and versionName in C ++, I was able to get the packageName with the following code.

```
static jstring getpkg(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject activity) {
    jclass android_content_Context =env->GetObjectClass(activity);
    jmethodID midGetPackageName = env->GetMethodID(android_content_Context,"getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring packageName= (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(activity, midGetPackageName);
    return packageName;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918762/how-to-get-app-package-name-or-applicationid-using-jni-android refer this link

Comment: It helps to get the applicationID the same as the packageName, if it can get versionName will be much better.

Answer (score 1):

In java you can do the following:

```
String VersionName = this.getPackageManager()
                                    .getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0)
                                    .versionName;

String VersionCode = this.getPackageManager()
                                    .getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0)
                                    .versionCode;
```

Comment: Yes it is the answer to the code in Android, but I need to get this information inside the C ++ file